# Font style inside PCA Graph (and ggcorrplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I am trying to prepare an article for publication and I am having trouble getting a  consistent font style in my PCA charts. I am using the fviz_pca_var function. The code I am using is

```
library(ggplot2)
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)

irispca <- PCA(iris,quali.sup = 5)
fviz_pca_var(irispca, col.var = "black", ggtheme = theme_classic2(base_family = "Times"))
```

The resulting chart looks like this. The problem being the text inside the chart is Arial not Times

I also tried this

```
add_el <- theme_grey() +
+   theme(text = element_text(family = "Times"))
```

fviz_pca_var(irispca, col.var = "black", ggtheme = add_el)

and this

```
fviz_pca_var(irispca, col.var = "black") + theme(text = element_text(size = 14,  family = "Times"))
```

Even the Scree plot gives the same issue

```
fviz_eig(irispca, addlabels = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 30), font.family = "Times")
```

Any tips would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)

irispca <- PCA(iris,quali.sup = 5)
```

Here is the solution.
I can't post the plot due to the low repuration on Stackoverflow.

```r
fviz_pca_var(irispca, col.var = "black", font.family = "Times")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>